# Subscribing in angular service constructor brakes my drag and drop functionality

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular8, angular-services

I have a drag-and-drop.service that depends on lists.service.
The d&d service looks like this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

export class DragAndDropService {
  private lists: any[] = null;

  private dropListSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IDropListState>({
    Lists: this.lists,
    IsOpen: false,
    Delay: 0
  });

  constructor(private ls: ListsService) {
    // TODO: Subscription breakes the drag and drop functionallity
    this.ls.onListsChanged().subscribe(x => {
      this.lists = x;
      console.log(x);
      this.emitDropListState();
    });
  }

  onDropListStateChange() {
    return this.dropListSubject.asObservable();
  }

  open() {
    this.emitDropListState(true);
  }

  close(delay: number) {
    this.emitDropListState(false, delay);
  }

  add(id: string) {
    this.ls.addNewList(id);
    this.emitDropListState();
  }

  remove(listId: string) {
    this.ls.deleteList(listId);
    this.emitDropListState();
  }

  emitDropListState(isOpen = false, delay = 0) {
    this.dropListSubject.next({
      Lists: this.lists,
      IsOpen: isOpen,
      Delay: delay
    });
  }
}
```

the lists.service looks like this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})

export class ListsService {
  private listsFromStorage: BehaviorSubject<any[]>;

  private lists: any[];
  private STORAGE_LIST_NAME = "lists";

  constructor() {
    this.lists = JSON.parse(
      window.localStorage.getItem(this.STORAGE_LIST_NAME)
    );
    this.listsFromStorage.asObservable();

    this.listsFromStorage = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(this.lists);
  }

  onListsChanged() {
    return this.listsFromStorage.asObservable();
  }

  deleteList(listName: string) {
    this.lists = this.lists.filter(x => {
      return x.Name !== listName.trim();
    });

    this.saveAndEmmit();
  }

  addNewList(id: string) {
    //TODO: List adding todo
    console.log("TODO: Add List: id-", id);
    this.saveAndEmmit();
  }

  saveAndEmmit() {
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      this.STORAGE_LIST_NAME,
      JSON.stringify(this.lists)
    );

    this.listsFromStorage.next(this.lists);
  }
}
```

NOW: When i use the angular material d&d stuff, this error is thrown:

> [image: Blockquote]

When I remove the subscription in the d&d service, it doesn't throw the error.

Is this approach reasonable or how else can I imitate this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's that drag-drop library you are using? Can you share the link please. Thanks

Comment: I use angular Material. https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview